# Why magento2 outputs the query while showing data from ResourceModel collection Factory..?

Tags: magento2, collection, query, resource-model, factory

```
protected $productCollectionFactory;


public function __construct(
        .....
        \Custom\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        ...
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
       ....
    }

   public function execute()
   {
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create()->load(1)->getData();
    var_dump($collection);
die();
    return $collection;   
    }
```

Output:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `custom_mymodule` AS `main_table`
/home/magento2/Custom/MyModule/Controller/Product/products.php:68:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'product_name' => string 'Moongoose' (length=30)
      'product_sku' => string 'Moo74' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have pass 1 in load() method

> Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb check in abstrctDb class

```
                 public function load($printQuery = false, $logQuery = false)
                    {
                        if ($this->isLoaded()) {
                            return $this;
                        }

                        return $this->loadWithFilter($printQuery, $logQuery);
                    }
```

if you pass 1 it means $printQuery=true
that's why query printed